# Zombie is working fine but it's prefab is creating issue in animation in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am creating a FPS shooter game in unity.Bellow is the script i have used on zombie and it's working fine but when i create prefab of that zombie it also works but it stops doing the attack animation and other things are working fine what should i do now? Please help me.....I have used three different zombies and used same script on them all are working great but when i create prefab of those zombies they again create issue and stops doing attack animation although my health is decreasing when they come closer. please help me out in this i don't know if my code is wrong or i have done any mistake in unity settings but it's very difficult to do it and make it correct what should i do guys it's my final year project project and i am stuck in this very hard situation.

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerChaseWithoutFaceFollowing : MonoBehaviour {

        public Transform player;
       // public Transform head;
        // public Transform sword;

        static Animator anim;

        //bool pursuing = false;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); // assigning component
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position; //to get the direction 


           // float angle = Vector3.Angle(direction, this.transform.forward);
            // float swordmovement = Vector3.Angle(direction, head.up);
            if (anim.GetBool("Death"))
            {
                anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
                anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 10 )
                {
                    direction.y = 0;
                    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f); // rotate enemy to player
                    anim.SetBool("isIdle", false); // no more idle state

                    if (direction.magnitude > 3) // start walking
                    {
                        this.transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.5f);
                        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true); //start walking animation
                        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
                    anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                    anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                    //pursuing = false;
                }

            }
            //if (anim.GetBool("isAttacking") && !anim.GetBool("isWalking"))
            //{
            //    AudioSource EnemyAttack = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            //    EnemyAttack.Play();
            //}

            //if (anim.GetBool("isAttacking") && !anim.GetBool("isWalking"))
            //{
            //    PlayerHealthBar.value -= 2;
            //    Debug.Log("Hit");
            //    //anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);

            //}
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my image below

[zombie animator panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdRxQ.png)

Your way to set parameter may mislead. Try using int as animator transition parameter, so instead of doing

```
anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
```

you do

`anim.SetInt("State",0);`